# How do I set up multiple folders for access on localhost in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, git

I'm working on practicing my server setup/command line/Git/ruby on rails skills in Ubuntu, and  I have set a folder up with Ruby on Rails to do so. This folder has a rails server which can be accessed at `http://localhost:3000`. In addition, I am also setting up folders on the same level which contain local Git repositories. While I am developing and hosting on Ubuntu, I am testing for IE bugs in three virtual Windows machines. To do this with the rails server, I can access `http://192.168.1.3:3000` (or something similar) in the virtual machine for my virtualized Ubuntu.

How can I set my git folders up to be accessed the same way, despite the fact that they are not in the folder the rails server is installed in, and are not always going to be ruby projects?

For clarification, my folder setup is like this:

```
home
 www
  rails_project (localhost:3000/192.168.1.3:3000)
  forked_git_repo
  forked_git_repo_2
  my_local_git_project
  just_some_code_i_wanna_browser_test
```

Comment: For this case, make `/home/www/` your documentRoot for the virtualhost. Then you can access the git folders like `http://192.168.1.3/forked_git_repo/`. Try it out.

Comment: This makes sense, and I've set the server root to what you suggested, but it's saying: "Not Found" when I go try to go to: http://localhost/forked_git_repo/ . Also, the Apache config file says: "# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path."Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I looked around a little more and saw that I was changing the wrong setting. However, now when I set `DocumentRoot "/home/www/"`, it still doesn't seem to work. Also, there didn't seem to be a default setting for that in apache2.conf.

Comment: I got it! I had to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` , not `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to edit `DocumentRoot`. Then, I needed to restart the server. @Bibhas, if you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: You did do some good research. Kudos. :) Ok. Will add it as answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, make `/home/www/` your `DocumentRoot` for the virtualhost. Then you can access the git folders like `http://192.168.1.3/forked_git_repo/`. Try it out.

**Update:** The default settings are at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` as pointed out by the questioner [@CodeJunkie](https://superuser.com/users/115176/codejunkie).